# How to filter pokemon in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, react-native, user-interface

I am trying to filter out pokemon in my searchbar component however when I type into the search bar the name of the component, nothing happens to the list. I have been searching online for solutions but other examples are too complex to implement into my code. I am consoling.log the input from the search bar component and it logs the input text. But just dont know how to filter out the pokemon. If anyone can help me I will really appreciate it!

```
// Home.js(Where pokemon ifo is coming from in the componentDidiMount abd then I pass down a function to the searchbar component)

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text , Button, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { GlobalStyles } from "../styles/GlobalStyles";
import PokeDetails from "./PokeDetails";
import SearchBarComponent from "../components/SearchBar";
import PokeBanner from "../components/PokeBanner";

class Home extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            dataSource: [],
            filteredPokemon:[]
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=27`)
            .then((res)=> res.json())
            .then((response)=> {
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    dataSource: response.results,
                })
                console.log("RESPONSE",response)
                console.log("RESPONSE.RESSSULTS",response.results)
            })

    }

    filterPokemon =(textToSearch)=> {
        const allPokemon = [...this.state.dataSource];
        this.setState({
            dataSource: allPokemon.filter(pokemon=> pokemon.name.toLowerCase().includes(textToSearch.toLowerCase()))
        });

        console.log("TextToSearch",textToSearch)
    }

    render() {

        const showIndicator = this.state.isLoading == true ? <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" /> : null;
        return(
            <View style={GlobalStyles.container}>
                <SearchBarComponent filterPoke={this.filteredPokemon} style={GlobalStyles.searchBar}/>
                <PokeBanner/>
                <View style={GlobalStyles.activityIndicator}>{showIndicator}</View>
                <View style={GlobalStyles.pokeFlatList}>
                <FlatList
                    contentContainerStyle={{paddingBottom: 70}}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.name}
                    numColumns={3}
                    data={this.state.dataSource} 
                    renderItem={({item})=> 
                    <View style={{flex: 1,justifyContent:"center", alignItems:"center", flexDirection: "row", marginBottom: 50, padding: 10}}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('PokeDetails', 
                    {item ,imageUrl: `https://projectpokemon.org/images/normal-sprite/${item.name}.gif`})}>
                        <PokeDetails imageUrl={`https://projectpokemon.org/images/normal-sprite/${item.name}.gif`} name={item.name}/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                    }/>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}


export default Home;





// SearchBarComponent(Where I take the function passed down as a prop and use it in the updateSearch method)

import React from "react";
import {View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';
import { GlobalStyles } from "../styles/GlobalStyles";


class SearchBarComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    search: '',
  };

updateSearch=()=> {
  this.props.pokeFilter(this.state.search);
  console.log(this.state.search)
}



  render() {
    const { search } = this.state;
    console.log(search)
    return (
        <View style={GlobalStyles.searchBar}>
            <SearchBar
                placeholder="Search pokemon..."
                onChangeText={text=>this.setState({search: text})} 
                value={search}
            />
        </View>

    );
  }
}


export default SearchBarComponent;




[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call your `updateSearch` function when the user wants to search for a pokemon.

There are multiple ways to do that such as you can keep a separate button to handle submit function or call `updateSearch` inside `onChangeText` of your search bar component as below,

```
<SearchBar
    placeholder="Search pokemon..."
    onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
    value={search}
/>
```

now change your `updateSearch` to handle serach text

```
updateSearch = (text) => {
  this.setState({ search: text });
  this.props.pokeFilter(this.state.search);
}
```

Also change the props of `SearchBarComponent` component as (***make sure to use correct name***)

```
<SearchBarComponent pokeFilter={this.filterPokemon} style={GlobalStyles.searchBar}/>
```

But you have to keep a temp variable to store all your pokemons. Because you need to filter data from all pokemons when user midified the search field.

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=27`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                // keep a temp to store all pokemons
                pokemons: response.results,
                dataSource: response.results,
            });
        });
}
```

Now you can use your filter function

```
filterPokemon = (textToSearch) => {
    // load all pokemons from temp
    const allPokemon = [...this.state.pokemons];
    this.setState({
        dataSource: allPokemon.filter(pokemon => pokemon.name.toLowerCase().includes(textToSearch.toLowerCase()))
    });
}
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: Thanks again man! I remember you from one of my questions yestarday! Appreciate it man!

Answer (score 0):

You should set FilteredPokemon as all pokemon when you do the first petition and pass that state to the FlatList. That way you will only show the filtered pokemon:
Then when you modify the search you will just filter on the allPokemon state and set it to the filtered. Let me just show it:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=27`)
        .then((res)=> res.json())
        .then((response)=> {
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                dataSource: response.results,
                filteredPokemon: response.results,
            })
            console.log("RESPONSE",response)
            console.log("RESPONSE.RESSSULTS",response.results)
        })

}

filterPokemon =(textToSearch)=> {
    const allPokemon = [...this.state.dataSource];
    const filteredPokemon = allPokemon.filter((pokemon) => 
        pokemon.name.toLowerCase().includes(textToSearch.toLowerCase()))
    this.setState({
       filteredPokemon 
    });

    console.log("TextToSearch",textToSearch)
}
```

Any problem just let me know and I will be happy to help!